# Time Complexity of an If Else Statement

Tags: if-statement, time-complexity, computer-science

I am trying to learn about time complexity. I have done some research on the step method but am not sure how to call use it with a IF ELSE statement. The problem is below. I think the time complexity is O(n) but I am not sure.

The function is given is below with some of my //notes/ thoughts Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated :)

```
FUNCTION fibonacci(number)
 IF number < 1 THEN    // constant operation, will only run once
   ERROR
 ELSE IF number = 1 or 2 THEN //constant operation, will only run once
   RETURN 1
 ELSE  //these only run if the number isnt one or two so it could be N times- but not sure?
   CALL fibonacci WITH number - 2 RETURNING twoBack
   CALL fibonacci WITH number - 1 RETURNING oneBack
   RETURN twoBack + oneBack
 END IF
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: The time complexity in fact is _not_ `O(n)`, but rather is some exponential of `n`.  The reason is that each call to `fibonacci` will generate _many_ other calls.  The problem with your recursive approach is that `fibonnaci(x)`, for some input `x`, will be potentially recomputed many times over and over again.  Google "dynamic programming fibonacci" to learn about a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you! while learning sometimes the hardest part is knowing the correct way to look for the information.

Comment: For fun, write out on a piece of paper all the calls which happen for `fibonacci(3)`, then do the same for `fibonacci(4)` and onwards.  You will quickly see how wasteful the recursive approach becomes.